# Encountring very fundamental problem with react, why item.id in my case is increasing by +2?

Tags: reactjs

hi i have just started learning react and facing problems in understanding fundamentals ,
here i am creating basic todo app
***question is***
why item-id in seq of 1,3,5,7.... as show in image attached
How do i slove this ?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

let counter = 0;

function App() {
 const [text, setText] = useState("");
 const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

const createTodo = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setText('')
  setTodos((oldTodos) => [...oldTodos, { todo: text, id: counter++ }]);
};

 return (
   <div className="App">

     <form onSubmit={createTodo}>
     <input
      type="text"
      value={text}
      onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
     ></input>
     <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
     </form>

   <ul>
    {todos.map((item) => {
      return (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.todo}-{item.id}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>

 </div>
 );
}
```

export default App;

browser output
**[[image: output in browser1]**

***Any better approach to slove issue??***

Comment: To investigate this, I would add `console.log(todos)` to see what is in the list.

Answer (score 2):

try this code instead

```
 const [text, setText] = useState("");
 const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
 const [count , setCount] = useState(0);

const createTodo = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setCount(count++)
  setText('')
  setTodos((oldTodos) => [...oldTodos, { todo: text, id: count }]);
};
```

Comment: Your solution works but why OP’s doesn’t? I for one am more interested in the “why”.

Comment: you should manage the states of your application inside of your component and organize those insides of ````useState```` hook

Comment: You cannot mutate `count` value directly, but change it to `setCount(count + 1)` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: getting rid of `StrictMode` mode, you will produce the desired output.

### But why?

##### With StrictMode:

```
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  console.log("Renders!"); // Add logging to see what happens
  console.log(todos);
```

On page load, console shows:

```
Renders!
[]
Renders!
[]
```

the page reders twice, which is expected, and now we submit a string value `one`, and the console shows:

```
Renders! // First render
[{todo: "one", id: 0}]

Renders! // Second render
[{todo: "one", id: 1}] // notice id value
```

From output, we can see the id of first todo item is already at 1, and it should've been zero, the starting value of `counter`. That's because the setter invoked twice, as the page renders twice:

```
setTodos((oldTodos) => [...oldTodos, { todo: text, id: counter++ }]);
```

##### Without StrictMode:

```
Renders!
[{todo: "one", id: 0}]
```

Only renders once, and id is the starting point 0.

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pasteur-bwfpuj?file=/src/index.js) and for learning material recommend [react beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

Comment: How do you enable/disable strict mode?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice At Index.js file, you can delete `<StrictMode>`

Answer (score -1):

`counter++` means you are re-assigning the value of the counter variable. `counter = counter +1`, `counter += 1` are alternatives for it. So what you can try is you can first change the value of the variable and then assign it to the id property.

```js
let counter = 0;

function App(){
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

    const createTodo = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setText('');
        counter++; // or counter += value or counter = counter + value;
        setTodos((oldTodos) => [...oldTodos, { todo: text, id: counter }]);
    };

}
```